# Making a background like a radio button switching between an on state on off state when clicking on it

Tags: javascript, html

I'm hopelessly lost on this one.

Html:

```
<p onclick="on(&quot;test&quot;, testSwitch)" id="test" style="background:red;">TEST THIS STUFF OUT</p>
```

Js:

```
var testSwitch = 0;
function on(element, machineSwitch){
    if (machineSwitch==0){
        document.getElementById(element).style.display="green";
        document.getElementById(element).innerHTML="STATUS:ON";
        machineSwitch=1;
    }
    else if(machineSwitch==1){
    document.getElementById(element).style.display="red";
    document.getElementById(element).innerHTML="STATUS: OFF";
    machineSwitch=0;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to make it so that the background changes to green when its clicked then red when its clicked again. The background should cycle through these. I also need a variable to control it because I am using it to control a whether a loop happens or not elsewhere.

Comment: did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `element.style.background` to change the BG Color.

HTML

```
<p onclick="on(this)" id="test" style="background:red;">TEST THIS STUFF OUT</p>
```

JS

```
var testSwitch = 0;
var machineSwitch = 0;
function on(element){
    if (machineSwitch==0){
        element.style.background="green";
        element.innerHTML="STATUS:ON";
        machineSwitch=1;
    } else if(machineSwitch==1){
        element.style.background="red";
        element.innerHTML="STATUS: OFF";
        machineSwitch=0;
    }
}
```

It is more convenient to use the `data-` attributes and use `case` `switch` for more flexibility if you are adding more colors to it.

JS

```
function on(element){
    switch (element.getAttribute('data-machineSwitch')) {
        case '0':
            element.style.background="green";
            element.innerHTML="STATUS:ON";
            element.setAttribute('data-machineSwitch', '1');
            break;
        case '1':
            element.style.background="red";
            element.innerHTML="STATUS:OFF";
            element.setAttribute('data-machineSwitch', '0');
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<p onclick="on('test', testSwitch)" id="test" style="background:red;">TEST THIS STUFF OUT</p>
<script>

var testSwitch = 0;
function on(element, machineSwitch){
    if (machineSwitch==0){
        document.getElementById(element).style.backgroundColor ="green";
        document.getElementById(element).innerHTML="STATUS:ON";
        testSwitch=1;
    }
    else if(machineSwitch==1){
     document.getElementById(element).style.backgroundColor="red";
     document.getElementById(element).innerHTML="STATUS: OFF";
     testSwitch=0;
    }
}

 </script>
```